# How to initialize Parse without exposing application id?

Tags: android, security, parse-platform

Currently, initializing the [Parse](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android) framework requires sending the application id to parse server, as in this sample code:

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
      .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
      .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
      .build()
    );
```

This is problematic because if the app runs on Android 6 or earlier, a sniffer could read this app id and use it to access the app's Parse database.

Is there a way to initialize Parse in a more secure way ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is.  I think the best you can do is:

- Accept only HTTPS connections to your parse server

  - Put ACLs on everything
  - Turn off client table creation

Then I think the attacker could not do anything that user wouldn't be allowed to do anyway.  For example, if the ACL allowed that user to read an object, but not to update or delete it, that's all the attacker could do outside of your app.

Comment: Interesting, but an attacker could still flood the database by creating many entries in the User table

Comment: Yes I think that's right.  You could partially mitigate that by requiring email verification before allowing a user to do anything, though I'm not sure how easy that would be.  It might require using server side code which in the parse.com days was not that great.  If you did get attacked in that manner it wouldn't be too difficult to periodically purge unverified users.